# How to fix aws-cli cloudfront update distribution command?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been trying to execute below command but it resulted in an error

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE \ 
--Origins '{ "Items": [{
                    "OriginPath": "", 
                    "CustomOriginConfig": {
                        "OriginSslProtocols": {
                            "Items": [
                                "TLSv1", 
                                "TLSv1.1", 
                                "TLSv1.2"
                            ], 
                            "Quantity": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }'
```

> ERROR:::   Unknown options: { "Items": [{
>                       "OriginPath": "",
>                       "CustomOriginConfig": {
>                           "OriginSslProtocols": {
>                               "Items": [
>                                   "TLSv1",
>                                   "TLSv1.1",
>                                   "TLSv1.2"
>                               ],
>                               "Quantity": 3
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }
>               ]
>           },  --Origins

I have to remove `cloudfront  :  OriginSslProtocols:SSLv3`

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE \ 
--Origins '{ "Items": [{
                    "OriginPath": "", 
                    "CustomOriginConfig": {
                        "OriginSslProtocols": {
                            "Items": [
                                "TLSv1", 
                                "TLSv1.1", 
                                "TLSv1.2"
                            ], 
                            "Quantity": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }'
```

1) How to fix above code,if not possible if there any command other than below command to disable/remove  OriginSslProtocols:SSLv3

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE --distribution-config  file://secure-ssl.json --if-match E35YV3CGILXQDJ
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the right command and it should be possible to do what you want.
However, it is slightly more complicated.

The corresponding reference page for the cli command *aws cloudfront update-distribution* says:

> When you update a distribution, there are more required fields than when you create a distribution.

That is why you must follow the steps which are given in the cli reference [1]:

> - Submit a GetDistributionConfig request to get the current configuration and an Etag header for the distribution.
> - Update the XML document that was returned in the response to your GetDistributionConfig request to include your changes.
> - Submit an UpdateDistribution request to update the configuration for your distribution:
>
>   - In the request body, include the XML document that you updated in Step 2. The request body must include an XML document with a DistributionConfig element.
>   - Set the value of the HTTP If-Match header to the value of the ETag header that CloudFront returned when you submitted the GetDistributionConfig request in Step 1.
> - Review the response to the UpdateDistribution request to confirm that the configuration was successfully updated.
> - Optional: Submit a GetDistribution request to confirm that your changes have propagated. When propagation is complete, the value of Status is Deployed .

Fore info about the correct xml format is given in the *CloudFront API Reference* [2].

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateDistribution.html

Comment: Thank you Martin Löper. But if i have 20 distribution to be updated ,20json files need to be edited.      
•Is there any simple method(cli)which satisfies above requirement?
•Is it possible to merge below 2 commands 
aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id E29BDBENPXM1VE (linux command to remove ETag and DistributionConfig and SSLv3 )
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE --distribution-config file://secure-ssl.json --if-match E3Q13PU8O66E4Q                    
•What is the purpose of removing ETag and DistributionConfig parameters while updating the distribution.

Comment: Yes, there are examples out there how to accomplish this easily. I found them using the google search phrase "cloudfront update-distribution snippet". just adjust it according to your needs: https://gist.github.com/bendrucker/65f340e299ace46a012be2ce97af795f

Comment: I think semantically you must obtain and pass the ETag for the service to know which version of the configuration you want to update. This prevents conflicting queries to happen (e.g. when user A reads the config and changes it while user B does the same - when both are updating the configuration simultaneously only the first update succeeds while the second one fails. this prevents an unintended overwrite).
You do not "remove the ETag and DistributionConfig parameters". If you looked at the example snippet I pasted above, you see that they are extracted and used as parameters in the cli.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin Loper for your response.