# How to automate aws cloudfront update distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I need to update the cloudfront distribution to disable/remove originsslprotocol value:SSLv3

I tried to write python script,but i couldn't get succeeded

Can someone please provide python script to automate above requirement

https://www.cloudconformity.com/conformity-rules/CloudFront/security-policy.html

Comment: can anyone please help me out on this

Comment: What is the error you’re actually receiving?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ho to fix aws-cli cloudfront update distribution command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004274/ho-to-fix-aws-cli-cloudfront-update-distribution-command)